# Adding 'Sort' Icon on the header element using Material-Table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am creating a table, want to have 'filter' icon on each of the elements of the table header, which tell user the row is sortable, need help !!!

[image]

https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props

```
        return (
            <div className="rank-table">
                <MaterialTable
                    columns={(isMobile ? mobileColumnArray : desktopColumnArray)}
                    data={dataArray}
                    localization={{
                        toolbar: {
                            searchPlaceholder: "Search for Country"
                        }
                    }}
                    options={{
                        exportButton: true,
                        showTitle: false,
                        exportFileName: moment().format("YYYY-MMMM-DD").toString() + " COVID-19 Data",
                        // searchFieldStyle: {
                        //     border: "1px solid black",
                        //     width: "100%"
                        // },
                        searchFieldAlignment: "left",
                        fixedColumns: {
                            left: 1,
                            right: 0
                        },
                        pageSize: 15,
                        pageSizeOptions: [15,20,25],
                        paginationType: "normal",
                        draggable: false,
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide your code? We need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  of the problem and what you have achieved.

Comment: we need more code to solve this problem